# My program doesn't open a text file to read it

Tags: java

`course.txt` file is not read by my code. It allows me to enter the file name, but doesn't open the file.

[image: my .txt file courses.txt]

```
package javaexam;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BufferReader {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader bf = null; // shows warning that assigned but never used
        String line;
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name");      
        try { 
            bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\MohammedArfa\\Desktop\\New folder\\" + scanner.next()));
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
            //shows warning that the buffer assignment is declared but never used
            System.out.println(fnfex.getMessage()+"The file was not found"); 
        }
        System.exit(0);
        try {
            while((line=bf.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage()+"Error reading file");
        } finally {
            System.out.println(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: You should really work on your code formatting. Then you would see this ***very wrong*** `System.exit(0);` in your code. Take more care next time. Voted to close, since looks like a "big" typo (because this `System.exit(0)` looks unwanted there).

Comment: no errors but doesnot show contents of the file

Answer (score 0):

Move the system.exit(0) into the catch statement above...

```
 try { 
     bf = new BufferedReader(new        FileReader("C:\\Users\\MohammedArfa\\Desktop\\New folder\\" + scanner.next()));
 } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
      //shows warning that the buffer assignment is declared but never used
      System.out.println(fnfex.getMessage()+"The file was not found"); 
      System.exit(0);
 }
```

If the system.exit(0) is not inside the catch then it is always being executed which terminates your program before you reach the print out loop.